# Regex to extract a sentence containg a word

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this

```
Good Morning 
Hello There - PROTECT FROM FREEZE
protect from freeze 
FORKLIFT UNLOAD -Please ship it with care
Thank you
```

I need a regex to match **PROTECT FROM FREEZE** from both lines and **FORKLIFT UNLOAD** on the other line
I have tried `.*FREEZE.*` and `.*FORKLIFT.*` (IGNORED CASE using re.IGNORECASE), But this regex selects the whole line.

This regex gives the output as follows:

```
Hello There - PROTECT FROM FREEZE
protect from freeze 
FORKLIFT UNLOAD -PLEASE HAVE SKID AT TAIL
```

Desired Output:

```
PROTECT FROM FREEZE
protect from freeze
FORKLIFT UNLOAD
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex for this? To match the exact substring `PROTECT FROM FREEZE` simply use `'PROTECT FROM FREEZE' in my_string`.

Comment: You could match only uppercase chars or spaces surrounding the words `[A-Z ]*\b(?:FREEZE|FORKLIFT)\b[A-Z ]*` https://regex101.com/r/zQ3PbW/1

Comment: You can use `[^-\n]*F(?:REEZE|ORKLIFT)[^-\n]*`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x7cJso/1).

Comment: actually there will be many sentences like this .... I cannot manually type in the sentence extacrt for all @Thomas

Comment: Then please edit your question to clarify what you mean by a "sentence" and which sentences need to be extracted.

Comment: Thank you@WiktorStribiżew ... I edited it for my sentences and extracted all ...

Comment: So, that worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
[^-\n]*F(?:REEZE|ORKLIFT)[^-\n]*
```

Or, if you need to make sure the `freeze` and `forklift` are whole words:

```py
[^-\n]*\bF(?:REEZE|ORKLIFT)\b[^-\n]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x7cJso/3)

**Details**

- `[^-\n]*` - zero or more chars other than `-` and a newline
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `F(?:REEZE|ORKLIFT)` - same as `(?:FREEZE|FORKLIFT)`, but a bit more efficient
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[^-\n]*` - zero or more chars other than `-` and a newline

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Y1tsVK):

```py
import re
text = 'Good Morning \nHello There - PROTECT FROM FREEZE\nprotect from freeze \nFORKLIFT UNLOAD -PLEASE HAVE SKID AT TAIL \nThank you'
res = re.findall(r'[^-\n]*\bF(?:REEZE|ORKLIFT)\b[^-\n]*', text, re.IGNORECASE)
print( [x.strip() for x in res] )
## => ['PROTECT FROM FREEZE', 'protect from freeze', 'FORKLIFT UNLOAD']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to match the *first* series of all caps words on each line, you could try this approach:

```py
inp = """Hello There - PROTECT FROM FREEZE
PROTECT FROM FREEZE 
FORKLIFT UNLOAD -PLEASE HAVE SKID AT TAIL"""

matches = re.findall(r'^.*?\b([A-Z]{2,}(?: [A-Z]{2,})*)', inp, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['PROTECT FROM FREEZE', 'PROTECT FROM FREEZE', 'FORKLIFT UNLOAD']
```